Plot of differentiated Fourier series
I have the following task: draw a plot of the sum of differentiated Fourier Series for $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.
Looking at the plot of Fourier series we can say that all coefs with $sin$ are zeroes and we will only have $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k \cos(kx)}$
so we get $f'(x) = 0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{-a_k \sin(kx) k}$
and I'm stuck here - what am I supposed to do next? and how to handle this $k$ that we got after differentiating $\cos(kx)$?

I'm not sure I understand your question, but $$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k, \sin(k x)$$ where $b_k=-a_k, k$.
